# Validación de errores desde API

Tags: php, json, laravel, laravel-blade

Estoy consumiendo una API que tiene unas reglas de las cuales si el valor que le envío es correcto, entonces me devuelve un array, sino me devuelve un mensaje de error. tengo lo. siguente:

```
public function code(Request $request){

        $client = new Client();

        $code = $request['code'];
        $user = $request['user'];

        $response = $client->get("http://Myruta/status/" .$code .'/'. $user );

        dd($response->getBody()->getContents());

        //return view('pages.home', compact('response')); //cuando sale bien devuelve a la vista la information
    }
```

ya tengo todo para cuando el valor es correcto. sin embargo cuando envío un valor incorrecto me devuelve lo siguente:

```
"{"errors":"empty"}"
```

La pregunta es: ¿como hago para que cuando me devuelva ese valor pueda enviar una alerta? He intentado hacerlo con `if(){}` pero no lo logro.

Esta es la API:

```
public function getContent($code, $user){
    $validationCode = Code::where("code", $code)->first();
    if (is_null($validationCode)) {
        return ["errors" => "empty"];
    }else if($validationCode->status==1){
        return ["errors" => "used"];    
    }else{ 
        return Elements::getContentBycode($code);
    }
}
```

Comment: yo probaria a meter la consulta en un try{} catch{}, y en el caso del catch devolver lo que te diga la excepcion PDO... quizas laravel pueda hacer algo de esa manera?

Comment: ¿Asumo que en la vista del método code puedes verificar si hay errores ?¿A qué tipo de alerta te refieres?

Comment: Me refiero a que envie una alerta informado al usuario que el valor no es correcto.  lo que estoy haciendo es induciendo un error para hacer pruebas.

Comment: Hace una comparación en la base de datos y devuelve si el valor es correcto o no.

Comment: Bueno, pero eso no es más que una notificación en la vista, o un servicio que administre dichos mensajes.

Comment: Perdona mi ignorancia, ¿como se hace eso? Recuerda que la validación se hace en un servicio y necesito mostrar el resultado en la app externa que tengo